# date input type is not working in current release

Tags: dart

I have a simple code that worked in the previous dart release but not in the current one:

I tried on two separate machines. The calender is displayed but clicking the drop-down arrow does nothing - not even a stacktrace is generated.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe add some more information, like are you using polymer? Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. Most probably it's not Dart or polymer related but a bug in the underlying Chromium:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287159

Comment: Sorry for not adding some code. You can use the same code in the Dart Polymer example at the following URL https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web/days_until_birthday

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Same behaviour. Using Dartium/Chromium Version 31.0.1650.0 (224845).

Comment: The problem is in the current dart release - Win8 x64 is used. It worked on previous dart release

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The Dartium browser (which is just Chromium with the Dart VM) in the current Dart release hast this bug. But it's not a bug in Dart, it's a bug in Chromium. Star that bug and once it is fixed the next Dart release will probably have a version of Chromium where this works again (I don't know if they use the most current version of Chromium as a basis for Dartium, so it might take a while longer if they don't. If you want to know, you could try asking here: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc).